# AJV Multilevel/Nested JSON schema validation

Tags: javascript, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

Using the schema

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [     
      "person", 
      "animal"
  ],
  "person": {
      "title": "person",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
          "name"
      ],
      "properties": {
         "name": {
            "type": "string"
         }
      }
  },
  "animal": {
    "title": "animal",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This schema is valid when it is compared against this object

```
{
  "person": 0, 
  "animal": "dog"
}
```

I only want it to validate for the properties within person object (as it also has required properties). For example, only the following would be valid:

```
{
  "person": {
     "name": "myName"
  },
  "animal": "dog"
}
```

How can I ensure nested objects are validated in my schema using AJV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your schema, you need to put `animal` and `person` inside a `properties` object.

Currently, as those property keys are not within a `properties` object, they are classed as unkown keywords and ignored.

Otherwise, yeah, you have this correct.